# <meta title> for tagged pages on Tumblr

Tags: seo, tumblr, meta-tags, tumblr-themes, meta-title

I have a Tumblr blog using the theme Friends (tumblr.com/theme/39097). It has a useful meta-title on the index page and on all the posts but it is the same title for all tagged pages, it is always the title-name defined in admin of the blog on all tagged pages.

I would like to have a title like <"the tag of the page" + " | " + "the name of the blog>, i e if the name of the blog was "The Great Stuff Blog" and the tagged page in question was myblog.tumblr.com/tagged/Best-Gismo-Ever then i would like the meta title to be "Best Gismo Ever | The Great Stuff Blog".

It would basically correspond to how tumblr has the title on its own tagged pages, ie this page www.tumblr.com/tagged/gismo has the title "gismo | Tumblr"

How can I do that? If I got help with what to insert and where in the HTML for the theme I would be very happy!

Answer (score 2):

I found it!

The answer is on this page: [How to have different titles and meta tags for tag pages and index pages of Tumblr themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25331367/how-to-have-different-titles-and-meta-tags-for-tag-pages-and-index-pages-of-tumb)

This code should be included for the title:

```
{block:TagPage} {Tag} - {/block:TagPage}
```

In my case the title section now looks like this:

```
<title>{block:TagPage} {Tag} - {/block:TagPage}{block:SearchPage}{lang:Search results for SearchQuery} - {/block:SearchPage}{block:PostSummary}{PostSummary} - {/block:PostSummary}{Title}</title>
```